# Elastic search filter for distinct categories

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I made a simple mapping with three fields and i am analyzing one field which is text type and other fields are keyword type.
example

```
fields: Category_one, Category_two, Category_three.
```

Now i am searching the documents.

```
Get _search/cat
    {
    "size": 4,
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "Category_one.ngrams": {
            "query": "Nice food place in XYZ location",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        },
        "aggs":{
            "distincr_values":{
                "terms": {
                    "fields" : "Category_two"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

It's showing this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 10,
                "col": 5
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 10,
        "col": 5
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Kindly help me with this error. My main motive is to find distinct searches according `Category_two` field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe youre getting this error because of your query structure.
Your aggregations keyword must be outside (same level as) the query. At the moments your aggs is wrapped up inside the query.

Following this structure:

```
Get _search/cat
    {
    "size": 4,
      "query": {
             'query goes here'
       },
       "aggs":{
           'aggregation go here' 
      }
    }
```

Comment: I changed as you mention now it's showing a different error.
   "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "[terms] unknown field [fields], parser not found"

Comment: Post the full query you’re trying to execute. But judging by the error looks like you are requesting Terms agh on a field that doesn’t exist.

Comment: @lohitakshyogi if you have solved your problem and my answer above helped you solve the problem, please at least up-vote.